Protocol based url reading inside electorn
Can any one help me on this. I have an electorn application, and i have created the custom protocol named essc. From any browser(chrome,firefox, etc) if i browser like essc://www.electronjs.org/. That url need to open electron application first and remaining part of (URL www.electronjs.org/) need to bind in electron browser frame. Can this be achieved?

You have to tell your OS that this protocol should be handled by your Application (your electron).
Look for "How to register custom Windows/Linux/Mac ProtocolHandler"
